# Having issues with countifs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm just trying to make a small visibility map for myself for my job but I'm not the biggest expert at Excel. Whenever I used =countifs with filters in Excel, my cells, for some reason, vanish. Is there a way to keep my cells in place when I use the filter function? The cells are counting correctly it's just if I want to filter the numbers within their ranges, they vanish.

Here is my Excel before using filters:

[image]

This is what it looks like when I filter data out.

[image]

Comment: 1) You can put your formula section on a different sheet.
2) You can use the filter function (just for looking up something, not for changing)
3) use advanced filter, filter to a new range

Comment: Okay so I manage to add an advance search but when I filter the rows the cell still counts the numbers that have been filtered out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `SUMPRODUCT` and `SUBTOTAL` to get a count if and exclude values hidden (by filter).

For instance:
Text Values Range `A2:A7`
Number Values Range `B2:B7`
Criteria Range `D13` up to `D16`

Formula in `E13`:
`=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$7=D13)*(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET($B$2:$B$7,SEQUENCE(ROWS($B$2:$B$7),,0),,1))))`

`=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$7=D13)*(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET($B$2:$B$7,ROW($A$2:$A$7)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$7)),,1))))` for versions of Excel that do not have SEQUENCE.

The sumproduct creates an array of the condition being TRUE / FALSE (1 / 0 respectively) and the subtotal 103 counts the visible range only. OFFSET makes sure the subtotal doesn't return 1 end result but an array (cell by cell). The array of the condition * the subtotal array is the conditional count result

Unhidden result:
[image]

Hidden result:
[image]

This could also be used for SUMIF(S) by changing 103 to 109 in the SUBTOTAL function.

PS I'm unable to test it with the actual filter, since the app version of Excel does not support that, but I'm pretty sure it works as expected.

Comment: If you could give more clarity on your current COUNTIFS function we may be able to fit it to your desire. PS you could also avoid filtering and add it as an extra condition to your countifs. That way we would not have to use this SUBTOTAL solution containing OFFSET which is volatile (recalculates on each change anywhere in the document ).

Answer (score 1):

You've got your COUNTIFs on the same rows as your data. When you filter the data, it hides entire rows - including your COUNTIFS. As @Prema said, you could put the summary info on a separate sheet. Or if it's very compact, you could put the summary above the data.

Comment: I managed to set my data in another sheet but now when I filter my data it still counts the values that have been filtered out regardless of not being visible.

Comment: Ah, right… the filter hides the rows, but formulas still work on hidden rows.